# Making MonoDroid and Db4o work together

Tags: android, xamarin.android, db4o

I'm totally new to both subjects, MonoDroid and db4o, but taking a look on sample codes of both of them, I've got a pretty good idea of how each one works in their on way. Despite that, i just can't figure out how to make them both work together. Can anyone more experienced on the subject share some knowledge with me? I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: Always wanted to try that, but never did. I don't know what limitations MonoDroid imposes. Certainly you need to ensure that you write in the right directories, like with regular db4o on Android.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that I'd try to make sure is that the same file is being used for both reading/writing. If you try to open a file that does not exist db4o will simply open an "empty" db.